# How can I use the scanner class to scan a text file, pick out certain phrases, and count them?

Tags: java, file, text

I'm new to learning java, and am having a lot of trouble on this particular assignment. Normally I can figure out a solution after a bit of research, but this has me stumped.
It's a program to read through a file with different combinations of the letters "G" and "B" (ex. GG, GB, BB, BG) and I have to count how many lines the file is as well as how many instances each of those combinations pop up. Any help would be very appreciated!
I tried searching through all posts and tried something, but now it seems that my program won't run (not giving me any error messages though).

Source Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Family
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //define variables
        String lineRead = "";
        int numberLines = 0; //# of lines
        int bothMales = 0; //# of houses with both males
        int bothFemales = 0; //# of houses with both females
        int oneEach = 0; //#of houses with one male and one female
        File fileName = new File("test1.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("test1.txt"));

        while (inFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            numberLines++;
            inFile.nextLine();
            Scanner check = new Scanner(inFile.nextLine());
            while(check.hasNext())
            {
                if (inFile.equals("BB"))
                {
                    bothMales++;
                } 
                else if (inFile.equals("GG"))
                {
                    bothFemales++;
                }
                else if ((inFile.equals("GB")) || (inFile.equals("BG")))
                {
                    oneEach++;
                }
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Sample Size: " + numberLines);
        System.out.println("Two Boys: " + bothMales );
        System.out.println("Two Girls: " + bothFemales);
        System.out.println("One Girl and One Boy: " + oneEach);


    }//end main method
}//end class
```

Comment: Why are you trying to compare a Scanner object with a String object?

Comment: Does each line have one code or does each line have multiple codes?

Comment: @Bohemian In this case, each line has only one code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `nextLine` method of the Scanner

```
        while(check.hasNext())
        {
            String line = check.nextLine ();
            if (line.equals("BB"))
            {
                bothMales++;
            } 
            // etc
        }
```

Depending on your line, you maybe want to use the `trim` method on the `String` or use contains, rather than `equals`

Comment: Perfect! I also had to get rid of the uneccessary inFile.nextLine in the first while statement and this worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to analyze lines by making a String variable and setting it equal to the next line. It's easier to parse a string. Also why r u doing inFile.equals() in file your Scanner so that would equal a Scanner object not a string.

Iterate through the file like this:

While(inFile.hadNextLine()) {

```
 String nxtline = scan.nextLine():
 If(nxtLine.equals("BB") 
     Your code here repeat this for your other if statements.
```

I hope this helped if it did let me know in a comment.